# How this function call auto "f = [](int b)" possible?

Tags: c++, function, prototype

I have following program and shows the sum as 5.

```
int a = 1;
int main() {
auto f = [](int b) { return a + b; };
std::cout << f(4);

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Comment: it used to not be possible... :)

Comment: Are you asking how is it possible that 1 + 4 is 5?